# Images uploaded via Active Storage not displaying in Active Admin or on certain devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, activeadmin, heic

I'm encountering an issue where images uploaded via Active Storage in my Rails application are not displaying properly in Active Admin or on certain devices. Specifically, images uploaded via Active Storage are not showing up in Active Admin, and they are only visible on iPhone devices but not on desktop or Android devices.

Here's a brief overview of the problem:

I'm using Active Storage for handling file uploads in my Rails application.
Images uploaded via Active Storage are stored in a universally compatible format such as JPEG or PNG.
However, when I try to view these images in Active Admin, they do not display.
Additionally, the images are only visible when accessing the application from an iPhone device, but they do not appear on desktop or Android devices.